# Multivariate transformation

Tags: multivariate-analysis

Let x and y be random variables with the following joint density function: f(x,y) = e^-x for 0

If z= x+2y, what is the joint density function of x and z. Can someone explain how to find the joint distributions

I am a bit stuck on how to proceed. Can we find the individual PDF of x and z and then multiply. With that approach the answer doesn’t match

Comment: Please do not post new questions to improve old ones: just edit the original.

Comment: Edited the earlier one. Am new to the page hence didn’t know the protocol.apologies for trouble,. Request if you can help